# How do you turn off Application Insights Dependency Tracker?

Tags: .net-core, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to dump simple messages to my Application Insight log so I can monitor the health of my web service.  Things like "Service starting...", "Service Started.", etc. as well as exception messages.

But my log is flooded with these Dependency Tracking messages.  Things like the **Put** has been called, an **SQL Query** has been run.  I have no interest in these messages and it makes it damned near impossible to see real issues in that mess.

How do you turn this 'feature' off but still use Application Insight for basic progress message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to disable DependencyCollection by ApplicationInsights SDK, modify your ApplicationInsights.Config file to remove the DependencyCollectionTelemetryModule.

If you are using Asp.Net Core SDK, then use this instructions to remove the same:
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Auto-collection-modules-(Dependencies,-Perf-Counters,-Live-metrics-and-more.)#disabling-telemetry-module

From your descriptions, it looks like you are seeing some logs about dependency tracking? Are you on asp.net core sdk and using ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider? If you can elaborate a bit more on it, there might be a better solution.

Link to the doc about using ILogger and ApplicationInsights
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#frequently-asked-questions

Comment: It's a .Net Core 2.2 Project.  I don't recall loading up an SDK and I avoid the overhead if I can avoid it.  I've added the **Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore** and the **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsight** packages, but I can unload them just as easy.  In my appsettings file I have a **ApplicationInsights** key-value pair pointing to my AI instance.  And I have no idea what a ApplicationInsights.Config file is.

Comment: I'm happy to reverse the question: how do I just send all my ILogger information to Application Insights and not send any of this Auto-Dependency Collection info.  An example with code would be nice.  Better yet, an example with a sample appsettings.json.

Comment: Check the docs and see if it helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#aspnet-core-applications this section

Comment: You can remove Microsoft.ApplcationInsights.AspNetCore nuget and just keep Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.Then modify program.cs to have .ConfigureLogging(
            builder =>
                {
                    builder.AddApplicationInsights("ikey");

Comment: @cijthomas - OK.  That seems to work pretty well except I need the "ikey" to live in the appsettings.json file (because we want to direct the logged events to either the Development, Staging or Production AI instance depending on the environment).  Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/26577#issuecomment-479324834 This should show an example reading ikey.

Comment: The code referenced by @cijothomas is really the answer to my original question.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#frequently-asked-questions I updated the doc to cover reading ikey from appsettings.json